# Find a bit string in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, genetic-algorithm

I want to Search Some bits string like "101101" in a Simple Genetic Algorithm Model in NetLogo . There is this code in the Calculate-fitness:

```
set fitness length (remove 0 bits)
```

Can I find or search a string of Bits Like "101101" in this Algorithm .
Thanks

---

thanks for your Reply !
ok , but when I run the application , this error appear :
...

```
to calculate-fitness
  set fitness position "101101110" reduce word(list bits)
end
```

and for update code :

```
  to update-display
  set winner max-one-of turtles [fitness]
  ask patches
     [
       ifelse item pxcor ([bits] of winner) = 1
       [ set pcolor white ]
       [ set pcolor black ]
     ]
 end
```

and in "winner" appear this error :

```
**OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle but got NOBODY instead.**
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `(list bits)` produces a list with one element, which is `bits`.  If `bits` is a list, you just want `reduce word bits`.  Additionally, you have to decide what to do if `position` returns `false`.  (See the documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

You can readily search for substrings in a bit string with `position`. However, the Simple Genetic Algorithm Model uses lists, not strings.  If you wish, you can convert a list to a string quite quickly with `reduce`.  E.g.,

```
show position "110" reduce word [1 0 1 1 0]  ;; => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First define this:

```
to-report sublist-position [subl l]
  if length l < length subl [ report false ]
  if subl = sublist l 0 (length subl) [ report 0 ]
  let recurse sublist-position subl butfirst l
  if is-number? recurse [ report 1 + recurse ]
  report false
end
```

Now you can do:

```
observer> show sublist-position [1 1 0] [0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
observer: false
observer> show sublist-position [1 1 0] [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
observer: 5
```

This works on any kind of data. For your particular problem, you know you are only dealing with 0's and 1's, so I would actually go with Alan's solution, which is easier to understand and will almost certainly run faster, too.